# render layout false but still load view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in ruby to bypass application.html.erb but still use the corresponding view of the controller?

Right now I have

```
render :layout => false
```

But I get the following error from the view:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Below is my current posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.where('is_deleted' => false, 'is_hidden' => false).limit(15).order('created_at DESC')
  end 
  def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id], :conditions => 'is_deleted = false')
  end 
  def page
    render :layout => false
    @posts = Post.where('is_deleted' => false, 'is_hidden' => false).limit(15).offset(params[:page].to_i * 15).order('created_at DESC')
  end 
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't get this same error when removing the layout directive? I dont think the error is related to using `:layout => false`.

Comment: Yes, it works if I remove `render :layout => false`, the only issue of course being that it's including CSS (which I've included in application.html.erb)

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate, I've included my controller if it's any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def page
  render :layout => false
  @posts = Post.where('is_deleted' => false, 'is_hidden' => false).limit(15).offset(params[:page].to_i * 15).order('created_at DESC')
 end
```

should be

```
def page
  @posts = Post.where('is_deleted' => false, 'is_hidden' => false).limit(15).offset(params[:page].to_i * 15).order('created_at DESC')
  render :layout => false
end
```